# Unit-free ratios in \path let

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath, units

I want to compute pure ratios of distances in a `\path let` construction; for example, in the document fragment

```
\path let \p1 = (1cm, 2cm), \n1 = {\y1 / \x1} in ...
```

I would like `\n1` to be the number 2, not the string `2pt`, which is what TikZ actually writes because the computation involves a unit *somewhere*, even though they cancel out.  One bad solution is to write `\expandafter\strip@pt\n1` everywhere, but is there a way to signal to the PGF math engine that `\ifpgfmathunitsdeclared` (which controls this decision and is set somewhere inside `\pgfmathparse`) should be let to `\iffalse`?  I'm imagining a construction like

```
\path let \p1 = (1cm, 2cm), \n1 = {nounits(\y1 / \x1)} in ...
```

or some other thing that can be placed inside the math expression itself.

Comment: Not a direct answer: You can add `\pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro\ratio{\y1/x1}}` to the path (after `in`).

Comment: You could use `\def\m{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\strip@pt\n}` and then use `\m1` instead.

Comment: I think it is a bug of `pgf` package. There is a `real` function to remove the units, but it does not work here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trawling through the documentation again, I discovered the function `\pgfmathpostparse`, which is called after `\pgfmathparse`.  It is *supposed* to modify `\pgfmathresult` but there's no reason you can't just do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} \usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
 \def\pgfmathpostparse{\global\pgfmathunitsdeclaredfalse}
 \tikz \path let \n1 = {1pt} in node {\n1};
\end{document}
```

It prints "1.0"; commenting out the `\def` line makes it print "1.0pt" instead, so indeed this does what I want.  The `\global` is necessary because, apparently, `\pgfmathpostparse` runs inside a group.  Sorry for answering my own question.

Comment: Don't be sorry!